# Llamar a metodo de clase Padre a clase Hija o subclase

Tags: python, clase, clase-abstracta

estoy practicando lo de las clases abstractas y sus metodos, con este ejemplo

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod  # para convertir una clase a abstracta le ponemos ABC

class Animal(ABC):
     @abstractmethod                               #con esto hacemos los metodos abstractos, hay que hacerlo para c/metodo
     def __init__(self, nombre, edad, especie):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad
        self.especie = especie 

     def comer(self):
         return 'Comiendo...'
     
     def dormir(self):
        return 'Durmiendo...'
    
     @abstractmethod
     def getInfoAnimal(self):
         return f'la info del animal es, {self.nombre}, {self.edad}, {self.especie}'

class Anfibio(Animal):
     def __init__(self, nombre, edad, especie):
         super().__init__(nombre, edad, especie)
    
     def getInfoAnimal(self):
         print(f'el Animal es un Anfibio')
         return super().getInfoAnimal()

     def showStatus(self):
         super().dormir()

class Mamifero(Animal):
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, especie):
        super().__init__(nombre, edad, especie)

    def getInfoAnimal(self):
        print(f'El animal es Mamifero')
        return super().getInfoAnimal()
    
    def showStatus(self):
        super().comer()

anfibio = Anfibio('rana', 3, 'dudkmser')
print(anfibio.getInfoAnimal())
anfibio.showStatus()

mamifero = Mamifero('elefante', 45, 'mamfieros')
print(mamifero.getInfoAnimal())
mamifero.showStatus()
```

sin embargo al llamar al metodo comer y dormir en la clase Padre, tanto para las subclases anfibio y mamifero, no me imprime nada, probe colocando

```
print(anfibio.showStatus())
print(mamifero.showStatus())
```

y tampoco funciono, como seria para llamarlos en las clases hijas? o tendria que convertir estos metodos en abstractos para poder usarlos en las subclases?

Comment: No te imprime nada, o imprime None en pantalla? Por que tal como está tu código, lo que debería hacer es imprimir None. Edición: Ejecuté tu código y efectivamente imprime dos lineas con None.

Comment: si, ahorita que veo imprime None pero de igual manera si quito el print no imprime el status del Animal @DanteS.

Comment: No le estás indicando ni en showStatus, ni en comer, ni en dormir, que imprima algo en pantalla. Si no le dices al código que haga algo, no lo hace. La solución: usa la función print.

Comment: Okey, ya listo, listo ya funciono, gracias

Comment: De nada anonymuus c: